# Does Vivado 2015.2 support SV dynamic queing?

Tags: dynamic, queue, system-verilog

I am using Xilinx Vivado 2015.2 64 bit.

While running the following simulation I am getting the following error:

FATAL_ERROR: Vivado simulator Kernel has discovered an exceptional condition from which it cannot recover. Process will terminate.

Now the module:

```
module q();
wire a,b;
endmodule
```

Test bench for the module:

```
module tb_q();
reg a,b;
int gan [4] [$];
initial
    begin
    gan[2].push_back(67);
    $monitor("gan= %p",gan);
    end
endmodule
```

Any help will be deeply appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I believe simulator support of SystemVerilog is limited to a synthesizable subset. http://www.xilinx.com/support/answers/59002.html

Comment: Your comments were quite helpful. Does it mean all system Verilog constructs are not synthesizabe? Are there any other synthesis/simulation tools which provides complete synthesizable system Verilog support?

Comment: No. It means if Vivado simulation will not support any SystemVerilog construct unless it is also synthesizable. _Queues_ are not synthesizable. _Structs_ and _enums_ are synthesizable.

Comment: I just googled on what may be the use of non synthesizable subsets. May I conclude that Vivado 2015.2 does not support non synthesizable SV constructs EVEN FOR TESTING PURPOSES? But it supports Verilog non synthesizable constructs like $monitor which are mainly used for testing. Dave_59's response will make my understanding clear.